# accessing <a> target attribute nested below 3 divs

Tags: jquery, video.js, brightcove

I'm trying to change the target attribute of an a tag in the linked video example.
https://players.brightcove.net/5593175159001/experience_5b6c5e1d0de437001208bc9c/share.html

When you play the video a click here CTA appears in the bottom right hand corner. The default behavior for the player is to open the link in a new tab but I need to change that to the same tab. I've tried using:

```
$('#ee-link').find('a').attr('target','_parent');
```

and

```
$('.ee-link').children('a').attr('target','_parent');
```

When inspecting the CTA it is nested below 3 divs:

```
<div class="ee-interactivity">
 <div class="ee-link-container" data-corner="bottom-right">
   <div class="ee-link">
    <a target="_blank" href="www.google.com">Click Here</a>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help accessing the target attribute would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`ee-link` is a class not an `id`

```
$("div.ee-link>a").attr("target", "_parent");
```

Comment: good point thank you for that. I just gave that a shot but the target remains as `_blank`

Comment: @PerryLivingston I was just about to test it on your page in the browser console but it failed.  I cannot see jquery linked on your page...

Comment: if you inspect the page and go to sources > players.brightcove.net and click the share file under that folder you will find the jquery there.

Comment: @PerryLivingston either this or your first try work for me on firefox. Even they are using the same thing in their footer script. Look for `customJavaScript` and you'll find `$('div.ee-interactivity>div.ee-link-container>div.ee-link>a').attr('target', '_parent')`. Browser bug?

Comment: Likely the `div.ee-link>a` object doesn't exist on pageload and you need to run the code when it does initially show up by listening for the event that triggers it's creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using jquery next selector

```
$(".ee-link").next().attr("target", "_parent");
```

Answer (score 0):

The player is in an iframe so you need to do:

```
$('iframe').not(':first').contents().find('.ee-link>a').attr('target','_top');
```

With `.contents()` you access the stuff in the iframe.
But because the element is an iframe the `_parent` will show the page in the iframe, so you need to use `_top` .